# How to skip an Event if recently occurred not too long ago?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The not-working code:

```
Event = Something and SomethingElse and (ta.barssince(Event) > 20)
```

Of course, it won't work because at first time, the `Event` boolean variable is not declared yet.

Perhaps the question should be "*How to check whether a variable is defined or not*"? (I have tried to find the answer.)

Failed attempts (all the signals of the `Event` disappear):

```
Event = Something and SomethingElse
Event := Something and SomethingElse and (ta.barssince(Event) > 20)
```

and

```
Event = false
Event := Something and SomethingElse and (ta.barssince(Event) > 20)
```

Comment: You need a deeper understanding how Pine works as your examples show this is not the case (happens to everyone). Pine runs your code on every bar and whatever variables/values you create in that run, Pine will commit it to Series (like it is building metric tons of Arrays behind the scenes to save the result). But every next round of calculations starts clean.
The `var` example you got below circumvents this. Those variables are generated once and never cleaned up, they retain their value. This is why you will see many examples of those `var` variables placed inside an IF structure

Comment: Oh, I see! So that's the difference between "Something = 123" and "var Something ="Something"? 

(Obviously, this is what you've said. ) Thank you! :) Yeah, I admire everyday on what a great genius lays behind Pine Script. Just are you from the developer team?

Comment: …I mean: … and "var Something = 123" …

Comment: (you cannot edit your comment after 15 minutes, but you can copy/delete/rewrite them :D )

Comment: No, I'm just a humble junkie trying to understand Pine. All nice and good but if you dig deeper, you will pull your hair out. As I get it, unfortunately Pine is a not based on a real programming language so sometimes it has issues with the basics, like sequence/selection/iteration. It is completely missing debug features so you need to create your own mechanism where you try to print values to see where and why your script fails. I like it because it is like programming Assembly in the 90's, but that's not everyone's hobby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `var` counter. Reset it when your event takes place and increase it otherwise.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

n = input(2)

var bars_since_last_event = 0

is_green = (close > open) and (bars_since_last_event >= n)
bars_since_last_event := is_green ? 0 : bars_since_last_event + 1

plotshape(is_green)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! Would you please check on this question, too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167056/how-to-encode-pin-to-scale-z-into-pine-script-v5 It happened to be unanswered yet, there was a weekend in the meantime. <3